# Generic UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is rather generic question, I've read many answers, but I'm still wondering how it should be done properly.

When you have a table view that's like the Settings in iOS, where you have a table view cells with many different (in terms of type) cells (some with `UISwitche`, with `UIPickerViews`, for more details, with `UITextField`s, etc) should it be done using a `static tableView` or a `dynamic`? And what is the best way to go for achieving something like that?

And I'm asking for cases, where the information should be pulled from a backend like `Firebase` database for example.

Comment: Take a look at at the [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create custom cells in your table view and then you need to detect which type of cell you want to use and after that set cells.

Let´s say that you have three type of cells:

1. A cell with a `Switch` **(custom)**
2. A cell with a `textField` **(custom)**
3. A regular cell **(regular)**

In your `cellForRowAt` you need to detect which kind of cell you want to use. You can either do that by checking the `indexPath.row` if you have static positions or you can check the data type in your array and set the cell depending on that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SwitchCell", for: indexPath) as! SwitchCell
        // set cell values here
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell
        // set cell values here
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        // set cell values here
        return cell
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/) is a good guide of how you can create your custom cells and you can have as many custom cells as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it depends on your needs,

1. If you are going to show the UI elements like `UITextField`, `UISwitch`, etc.. based on certain condition or from api response means you can go with `dynamic tableView`. In dynamic tableView you can design multiple cells with different identifier or you can create `tableViewCell` in `nib`.
2. If you are always going to show the same UI elements means you can go with `static tableView`.

If you want to show UI elements based on response from `firebase database` means, you can go with `dynamic TableView`. Then only you will have control on you process and your data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing many times in the past.

You can include information in the data that will allow the table to dequeue the correct kind of cell and populate it.

For instance you might have a dictionary something like...

```
[
    "type" : "Switch",
    "on" : true,
    "text" : "Allow location access"
]
```

Now in your table view you can switch on the `type` in the dictionary to get the right type of cell. Then you can make sure the switch `isOn` and set the label text to `Allow location access`.

Of course, you'll need a lot more than just this particular case but the same basic principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

You gave already answer to your question.

1.You are getting data from Firebase. Then probably it could be dynamic.Then better to go with dynamic proto type cells.

2.So the data won't be same.Then make separate prototype cells for each type.Finally use the prototype cells based on 'Key' in dynamic data.

Even your Firebase data is Static above way is the best one.